# What is the PrintWorkflow_<6-hex-digits> service in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, printer, windows-services

We were having an issue this evening deleting a print job with a printer that was connected to a printer server... we couldn't get rid of the job, and on the workstation when the job originated we started the `PrintWorkflow_<6-hex-digits>` and the print job went away.

What is this service for?  I've never seen it in Windows, and I believe it's something new in Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PrintWorkflow_~` service appears to be related to the [Per-user services in Windows 10 and Windows Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows), so it's something new with **Windows 10** starting at **version 1709** according to the  *Per-user services* table and section of the Microsoft post.

- > > <sub>Applies to: Windows 10, Windows Server</sub>
  >
  > Per-user services are services that are created when a user signs into
  >   Windows or Windows Server and are stopped and deleted when that user
  >   signs out. These services run in the security context of the user
  >   account - this provides better resource management than the previous
  >   approach of running these kinds of services in Explorer, associated
  >   with a preconfigured account, or as tasks.
  >
  > [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows)

---

One example of what it could be used for seems to be talked about in the [Customize the print workflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-workflow-customize) post where it can customize the printing workflow experience.

- > **Overview**
  >
  > Developers can customize the printing workflow experience through the
  >   use of a print workflow app. Print workflow apps are UWP apps that
  >   expand on the functionality of [Microsoft Store devices apps
  >   (WSDAs)](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/),
  >   so it will be helpful to have some familiarity with WSDAs before going
  >   further.
  >
  > Just as in the case of WSDAs, when the user of a source application
  >   elects to print something and navigates through the print dialog, the
  >   system checks whether a workflow app is associated with that printer.
  >   If it is, the print workflow app launches (primarily as a background
  >   task; more on this below). A workflow app is able to alter both the
  >   print ticket (the XML document that configures the printer device
  >   settings for the current print task) and the actual XPS content to be
  >   printed. It can optionally expose this functionality to the user by
  >   launching a UI midway through the process. After doing its work, it
  >   passes the print content and print ticket on to the driver.
  >
  > Because it involves background and foreground components, and because
  >   it is functionally coupled with other app(s), a print workflow app can
  >   be more complicated to implement than other categories of UWP apps. It
  >   is recommended that you inspect the [Workflow app
  >   sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/print-oem-samples) while reading
  >   this guide to better understand how the different features can be
  >   implemented. Some features, such as various error checks and UI
  >   management, are absent from this guide for the sake of simplicity.
  >
  > [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-workflow-customize)

---

### Further Resources

- [Per-user services in Windows 10 and Windows Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows)
- [Customize the print workflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-workflow-customize)
- [PrintWorkflowBackgroundSession Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.printing.workflow.printworkflowbackgroundsession)